# Cannot get the SceneView to appear on ViewController

Tags: swift, arkit

I am brand new to Swift so please go easy on me!

I am basically having trouble with rendering an ARKIT `ARSCNView` with getting the error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is my code:

Initializing the view  here by connecting to the Storyboard

```
 @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
```

Here is the ViewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        
 // crashes here
 sceneView.delegate = self
}
```

Heres the ViewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.animatePulsatingLayer()
        self.dowloadModel()
    }
}
```

The animatePulsatingLayer just plays an animation while the model is downloading.

The Download model just downloads the model to     `weak var node: SCNNode!`

I have seen this code working before but since I have integrated SwiftUI into the project it has stopped working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly occurs when you **remove** or **do not add** the reference of the outlet with the .storyboard or .xib files.

I suggest you check them by right-clicking to the view on the storyboard and check if there is a connection.

Like this:
[image]

if there is no such connection you can simply connect them like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response! unfortunately I have previously done that. I was able to solve it by programmatically adding the ARSCNView to the view